# Custom sort lexicographically as int

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some elastic elements that have a string property that looks like `10/2021` and it need to be sorted as a int, but when I perform this query

```
 "sort": [
    {
      "myProperty": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
```

I get the lexicographic order.

```
1/2021
10/2021
100/2021
101/2021
102/2021
```

But I need it to sort by the first number and the year like this:

```
1/2020
2/2020
...
1/2021
2/2021
```

I can't figure out how to custom sort, is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Using [Scripted-Sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-sort-context.html) ...

**Not Recommended with large data-set:** It will take time as we are performing computations here

```
GET <>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script":{
      "type":"number",
      "script":{
        "lang":"painless",
        "source":"Integer.parseInt(doc['myProperty.keyword'].value.replace(\"/\",\"\"))" //<====== Replace myProperty.keyword with the keyword field or String field with field-data true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** i haven't added null checks in the script, just in case you have any document which don't have this field.

**Solution 2:**

- Store another Numeric field in elastic search which doesn't have "/"
- Sort based on that field
- Migrate the data of existing documents to the field using update_by_query API

This is the **Recommended** approach.